# Eclipse PDT (3.4) freezes while loading (Ubuntu 8.04, Sun Java 1.6)

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to run Eclipse PDT on Ubuntu 8.04 with Sun Java 1.6. The workbench screen loads up for a while and freezes, and I get an `.SWTError: XPCOM error -2147467262` after that. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try launching eclipse with the -clean tag.  That might sort it out.  Check out the following:

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html

Alternatively, you can delete the .snap file that exists in your workspace folder.  Note this will result in loss of workspace state, but you can recover by reimporting projects, setting up your perspectives again etc...  This is really a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Eclipse wasn't working with the JVM that comes with Ubuntu. Try downloading the Sun JVM and change eclipse to launch with the -vm flag set to the path of the sun JVM.

EDIT:
Sorry I see now that you have the sun JVM, you need to launch Eclipse with the -vm flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your Firefox/XulRunner install.